# Is it possible to have multiple Discordjs select menus?

Tags: discord.js

Is it possible to have multiple select menus after running 1 slash command eg `/quiz foo` displays all quiz questions as a bunch of select menus

Something like this:

```
const row1 = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
  new MessageSelectMenu()
    .setCustomId('select')
    .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')
    .addOptions([
      {
        label: 'Select me',
        description: 'This is a description',
        value: 'first_option1',
      },
      {
        label: 'You can select me too',
        description: 'This is also a description',
        value: 'second_option1',
      },
    ])
)

const row2 = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
  new MessageSelectMenu()
    .setCustomId('select')
    .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')
    .addOptions([
      {
        label: 'Select me',
        description: 'This is another description',
        value: 'first_option2',
      },
      {
        label: 'You can select me too',
        description: 'This is also another description',
        value: 'second_option2',
      },
    ])
)

await interaction.reply({ content: 'Done!', components: [row1, row2] })
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have multiple `MessageSelectMenu` in one message and the way to send them is the way you have used. To execute a piece of code when an option is selected, all you have to add is:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {
  const valueClicked = interaction.values[0]
  // Execute whatever you want with the value
})
```

One thing to keep in mind is that you will get an error with your current code because both `MessageSelectMenu` in your code  have the same `customId`, so you might want to change that to a different value.